# SCRAM-SHA-256 not supported on mongodb 4.4

Tags: mongodb, hash

I'm trying to update use password using `db.updateUser()`. Supposedly, [mongo should support SHA-256](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.authenticationMechanisms) since 4.0 when using `passwordDigestor: "server"`. However, when I try, I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: Error: Updating user failed: SCRAM-SHA-256 not supported in authMechanisms :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.updateUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1436:11
@(shell):1:1
```

Here's the command(s) I used on the individual node of a replica set:

```
use admin
db.updateUser(
    "the_username",
    {
        pwd: passwordPrompt(),
        mechanisms: [ "SCRAM-SHA-256" ],
        passwordDigestor: "server"
    }
)
```

I'm running `4.4.15` binaries, and Feature Compatibility Version is `4.4`

Comment: When you upgraded your database, did you follow the [instructions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/release-notes/4.4-upgrade-standalone/)? I would expect such updates automatically while upgrade.

Comment: It's been a while since the upgrade to 4.0, where the change happened, but I'd suppose so. I answered my own question below, it turns out it was explicitly narrowed down to sha-1 in a config file I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a config file (on each individual node, mine was in `/etc`) which explicitly sets the mechanism set to only sha-1:

```
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1
```

If I change it to the folliwing it works as expected:

```
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-256,SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Comment: I guess you can also simply remove this parameter, because SCRAM is the default.

Comment: Sure, but every setting in the setup is under tight control to avoid unexpected behavior. I will remove sha-1 from the list when I know all passwords are changed, but right now both are in use, so I need to make sure that both are enabled. I don't want to risk sha-1 suddenly not being an option by default.